# Why does Docker use the same user and cgroup namespaces by default, when starting a new container?

Tags: docker, container, namespace

> Why does Docker use the same user and cgroup namespaces by default, when starting a new container?

I don't understand why Docker doesn't set up a new user namespace, so that `root` in the container isn't the same as `root` on the host.

In particular, since everything else is namespaced (besides cgroup), it really makes no sense not to completely isolate the container by default.

Can someone clarify why user namespaces are not enabled by Docker by default?

**Host:**

```
parallels@debian-gnu-linux-vm:~$ ls -la /proc/self/ns
total 0
dr-x--x--x 2 parallels parallels 0 Jan 30 17:29 .
dr-xr-xr-x 9 parallels parallels 0 Jan 30 17:29 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 parallels parallels 0 Jan 30 17:29 cgroup -> cgroup:[4026531835]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 parallels parallels 0 Jan 30 17:29 ipc -> ipc:[4026531839]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 parallels parallels 0 Jan 30 17:29 mnt -> mnt:[4026531840]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 parallels parallels 0 Jan 30 17:29 net -> net:[4026531957]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 parallels parallels 0 Jan 30 17:29 pid -> pid:[4026531836]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 parallels parallels 0 Jan 30 17:29 user -> user:[4026531837]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 parallels parallels 0 Jan 30 17:29 uts -> uts:[4026531838]
```

**Container:**

```
docker run -ti --rm debian:latest
root@210189a7a164:/# ls -la /proc/self/ns
total 0
dr-x--x--x 2 root root 0 Jan 30 16:30 .
dr-xr-xr-x 9 root root 0 Jan 30 16:30 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 30 16:30 cgroup -> 'cgroup:[4026531835]'
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 30 16:30 ipc -> 'ipc:[4026532287]'
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 30 16:30 mnt -> 'mnt:[4026532285]'
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 30 16:30 net -> 'net:[4026532290]'
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 30 16:30 pid -> 'pid:[4026532288]'
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 30 16:30 user -> 'user:[4026531837]'
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 30 16:30 uts -> 'uts:[4026532286]'
```